# multiple form handling Django python 3.x

Tags: python, django, web

i wanted to make simple page with two input forms
first one for posting data into file
second for taking index and deleting data from file
and both of them working independent
but so far i can only use first form like the second one its not even reached not a single method from second form is completed
here goes the code:

```
###############
#Views.py

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index/num.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = AddForm()
        form2 = DeleteForm()
        result = printResult()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'form2': form2,'result': result})

    def post(self, request):

        result = "result"

    ####____add option###################
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AddForm(request.POST)
            form2 = DeleteForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                text = form.cleaned_data['post']
                if (re.match("[0-9]+", str(text))):
                    text = text
                else:
                    text= None

                result = addToFile(text)
                args = {'form': form, 'form2': form2, 'text': text, 'result': result }
                return render(request, self.template_name, args)
            ##########
        ###____Delete option#######
            if form2.is_valid():

                index = form2.cleaned_data['dell']
                result = DeleteIndexFromFile(index)
                args2 = {'form': form, 'form2': form2, 'text': index, 'result': result }

                return render(request, self.template_name, args2)

            ##########
#forms.py
from django import forms

class AddForm(forms.Form):
        post = forms.CharField(required = False)
class DeleteForm(forms.Form):
        delete = forms.IntegerField(required = False)

#num.html
<div class="container">
    <p>
        <form  method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <form  method="delete" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form2 }}

            <button type="submit">Delete</button>
        </form>
    </p>
    <p>
    <h4>Data:  {{ text }}</h4>
    <h4>{{ result }}</h4>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a package called `django-shapeshifter` for doing this:

https://github.com/kennethlove/django-shapeshifter

In the interest of full disclosure, I am a contributor to the project.